# Defensive strategy for locking a operation or for avoiding concurrent data manipulation

Tags: mysql, sql, locking, blocking

I have a small PHP script that works on a fixed number of rows per step in a table
to create statistics until all rows are processed.

I wonder what the best strategy is to avoid concurrent runs of the script's
SQL/DML-statements if I

1. only know it's a MySQL database major release 5
2. don't know what engine is used (MyISAM or ...)
3. can only guarantee the database user has SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB is automatic:

In InnoDB you'd not have to lock anything at all, as MySQL is running in REPEATABLE READ transaction isolation level. When you begin a transaction and then SELECT something, with the first SELECT a transaction is started and as this is REPEATABLE READ, your view of the data will be consistent and unchanging until you COMMIT.

This implies that BEGIN, SELECT, SELECT, COMMIT in InnoDB REPEATABLE READ is different from SELECT, SELECT.

MyISAM is table locks:

In MyISAM, you'd `LOCK TABLES a, b, c READ, d WRITE` to put read locks on the tables you are reading and read/write locks on the tables you are writing to. It is impossible to build a list of locks incrementally with LOCK TABLES, so you have to lock everything you are going to touch in one go, and you are unable to touch anything you did not lock until you `UNLOCK TABLES`. LOCK TABLES requires an additional privilege, and it makes little sense to give SELECT priv without LOCK priv in MyISAM.

Generic is optimistic locking:

In MyISAM and in InnoDB without transactions, statements are executed atomically. That is sufficient to implement optimistic locking. In optimistic locking, assume you have a row with a primary key and data. Add the columns `state` and `owner` to it.

```
root@localhost [kris]> create table d ( id serial, d varchar(20), state enum('unclaimed', 'claimed', 'done') not null, owner integer unsigned not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.51 sec)

root@localhost [kris]> insert into d values (1, 'one', 'unclaimed', 0), (2, 'two','unclaimed', 0);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

root@localhost [kris]> select * from d;
+----+------+-----------+-------+
| id | d    | state     | owner |
+----+------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | one  | unclaimed |     0 |
|  2 | two  | unclaimed |     0 |
+----+------+-----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can now claim one or more rows for your processor:

```
root@localhost [kris]> update d 
    set owner = 1, state = 'claimed' 
where 
    state = 'unclaimed' 
order by id limit 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

The warning claims that this statement is not safe for replication, but the `ORDER BY` should make the `LIMIT` safe for replication. The result is that we have claimed one row for the owner with the owner id 1. This is safe in concurrent access because an UPDATE is being executed atomically:

```
root@localhost [kris]> select * from d;
+----+------+-----------+-------+
| id | d    | state     | owner |
+----+------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | one  | claimed   |     1 |
|  2 | two  | unclaimed |     0 |
+----+------+-----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We need to select back what we are currently working on, and process it:

```
root@localhost [kris]> select id, d from d where state = 'claimed' and owner = 1;
+----+------+
| id | d    |
+----+------+
|  1 | one  |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

We also need to set it to done when we are done:

```
root@localhost [kris]> update d set state = 'done', owner = 0 where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```